# Why can't scanf assign values to the input arguments?

Tags: c, scanf

My `C` code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[10];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    memset(s, 0xff, sizeof(s));
    scanf("%9s%d%d%d", s, &i, &j, &k);
    printf("%s,%d,%d,%d\n", s, i, j, k);
}
```

To avoid buffer overflow, I use `%9s` in `scanf`. But I find if the input string length is shorter than `10`, the result is as I have expected:

```
# ./test
short 1 2 3
short,1,2,3
```

While the length is longer or equal to `10`, `i`, `j` and `k` can't get the input:

```
# ./test
verylongstr 1 2 3
verylongs,0,0,0
```

How to understand `scanf`'s behaviour?

Comment: If you allocate 10 bytes and put 12 bytes there, *anything* you get is purely coincidental. You might get a crash, or a wrong answer, or the right answer, or demons flying out of your nose. The compiler is under no obligation to do anything sensible once you break the rules.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That's the whole point of using `%9s`, which he explained in his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell `scanf` to read at most 9 characters into `s`, so that's what it does. Once it has read 9 characters, it tries to read an integer into `i`, but the next input character is <kbd>t</kbd> (the tenth character). That cannot be converted to an integer, so the scan is terminated and `scanf` returns 1, indicating that it successfully read a single value.

Unfortunately you never check the return value. You should fix that.

The <kbd>t</kbd> is returned to the internal buffer, so the next scanf call will start with that character.